# What is the difference between "precise" and "accurate"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms

I often use these two words when I try to describe my experimental results. I wonder whether they can be used in the same situation. I searched these two words with *WikiDiff*, but still cannot get a clear explanation.

Comment: Easily [found here](https://labwrite.ncsu.edu/Experimental%20Design/accuracyprecision.htm).

Comment: But  the distinction made in Weather Vane's article is register-specific. I remember coming across it in school science. In the language in general, they're much more closely synonymous (easily found in respected dictionaries).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OP wrote "when I try to describe my experimental results".

Comment: Consider the two weather forecasts "it will be cloudy today" and "there will be stratus cloud today". The second is more precise but less likely to be accurate.

Comment: Precise is "Donald Trump weighs 236 pounds." Accurate is "Donald Trump's weight has been estimated at about 255 pounds."

Comment: Forget about WikiDiff. Look up one or both words (accurate, precise) in professionally-compiled dictionaries (Oxford, Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, etc) and see what the usage notes are.

Comment: @Weather Vane OP wrote 'What is the difference between “precise” and “accurate”?' and didn't add a 'science' tag. Or doesn't precision really matter on ELU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine the target to be made up of many squares, I've understood *precision* to be the size of each square, and *accuracy* to be how close you got to the desired square. This is based on the practice of *precision* being specified to a certain number of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) in scientific measurements.

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#ISO_definition_.28ISO_5725.29) notes that ISO 5725 provides the following definition:

> According to ISO 5725-1, the general term "**accuracy**" is used to describe the closeness of a measurement to the true value. When the term is applied to sets of measurements of the same measurand, it involves a component of random error and a component of systematic error. In this case **trueness** is the closeness of the mean of a set of measurement results to the actual (true) value and **precision** is the closeness of agreement among a set of results.

Answer (score 0):

**Precise** is "my watch says it is 10:35:06". But is this **accurate**? Maybe, maybe not. It depends on how carefully your watch was last set. You can get a precise experimental result, which is not at all accurate because someone bumped into the equipment and misaligned something or loosened a connection

Following is a recent, famous example of a **(fairly) precise** result of the speed of neutrinos which turned out to be **wildly inaccurate**. From [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2012/06/once-again-physicists-debunk-faster-light-neutrinos):

> Enough already. Five different teams of physicists have now
>   independently verified that elusive subatomic particles called
>   neutrinos do not travel faster than light. New results, announced
>   today in Japan, contradict those announced last September by a
>   170-member crew working with the OPERA particle detector in Italy's
>   subterranean Gran Sasso National Laboratory. **The OPERA team made
>   headlines after they  suggested neutrinos traveled 0.002% faster than
>   light, thus violating Einstein's theory of special relativity.** The
>   OPERA results were debunked months ago, however. So instead of the
>   nail in the coffin of faster-than-light neutrinos, the new suite of
>   results is more like the sod planted atop their grave.
>
> The OPERA team had timed neutrinos fired through Earth from the
>   European particle physics laboratory, CERN, near Geneva, Switzerland,
>   and found that they made the 730-kilometer trip to Gran Sasso 60
>   nanosecond faster than they would traveling at light speed. **But in
>   February, the OPERA team also discovered that  a loose fiber optic
>   cable had introduced a delay in their timing system that explained the
>   effect**.  (Emphasis added.)

This result is famous, but things like this happen all the time in labs.  That is one reason why results need to be independently confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

In 1923 [Theophilus Shickel Painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophilus_Painter), 1889 - 1969, an eminent cytologist, reported that there were **precisely** 48 human chromosomes. This was published in a respected scientific journal and was accepted in the scientific community for a period of 33 years.

In 1956, [Tijo and Levan](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16463025) published their work and were puzzled to discover they could only find **precisely** 46 chromosomes.

Not until [Ford and Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosome) also published their findings of 46 chromosomes, again in 1956, did it dawn on everyone that Painter's original data was **inaccurate.**

---

The difference between precision and accuracy is that the first is a matter of what is expressed, and the second is a matter of what is executed.

---

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149661?rskey=aOItKJ&result=2#eid). . .  (subscription required)

> Precise : Characterized by definiteness or exactness of **expression**

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1283?redirectedFrom=accurate#eid) . . (subscription required)

Accurate : **Executed** with care; careful.